# Unable to access the table header data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm developing an app using React. However, facing some issue with reflecting the {column.label} at column header field. The code works with any plain text but not for inputs in {}.
Below is the code for reference.

1. filename: tableHeader.jsx:

   ```
   import React, { Component } from "react";


   class TableHeader extends Component {
     raiseSort = (path) => {
       const sortColumn = { ...this.props.sortColumn };
       if (sortColumn.path === path)
         sortColumn.order = sortColumn.order === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
       else {
         sortColumn.path = path;
         sortColumn.order = "asc";
       }
       this.props.onSort(sortColumn);
     };

     render() {
       return (
         <thead>
           <tr>
             {this.props.columns.map((column) => (
               <th
                 key={column.path || column.key}
                 onClick={() => this.raiseSort(column.path)}
               >
                 {column.label}
               </th>
             ))}
           </tr>
         </thead>
       );
     }
   }

   export default TableHeader;
   ```
2. filename: moviesTable.jsx:

   ```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
   import Like from "./common/like";
   import TableHeader from "./common/tableHeader";

   class MoviesTable extends Component {
     columns = [
       { path: "title", lable: "Title" },
       { path: "genre.name", lable: "Genre" },
       { path: "numberInStuck", lable: "Stock" },
       { path: "dailyRentalRate", lable: "Rate" },
       { key: "Like" },
       { key: "Delete" },
     ];

     render() {
       const { movies, onDelete, onLike, onSort, sortColumn } = this.props;

       return (
         <table className="table">
           <TableHeader
             columns={this.columns}
             sortColumn={sortColumn}
             onSort={onSort}
           />
           <tbody>
             {movies.map((movie) => (
               <tr key={movie._id}>
                 <td> {movie.title} </td>
                 <td> {movie.genre.name} </td>
                 <td> {movie.numberInStock} </td>
                 <td> {movie.dailyRentalRate} </td>
                 <td>
                   <Like liked={movie.liked} onClick={() => onLike(movie)} />
                 </td>
                 <td>
                   <button
                     onClick={() => onDelete(movie)}
                     className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                   >
                     Delete
                   </button>
                 </td>
               </tr>
             ))}
           </tbody>
         </table>
       );
     }
   }

   export default MoviesTable;
   ```
3. fileName: movie.jsx:

   ```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
   import { getMovies } from "../services/fakeMovieService";
   import { getGenres } from "../services/fakeGenreService";
   import Pagination from "./common/pagination";
   import { paginate } from "../utils/paginate";
   import ListGorup from "./common/listGroup";
   import MoviesTable from "./moviesTable";
   import _ from "lodash";

   class Movies extends Component {
     state = {
       movies: [],
       genres: [],
       pageSize: 4,
       currentPage: 1,
       sortColumn: { path: "title", order: "asc" },
     };

     componentDidMount() {
       const genres = [{ _id: "", name: "All Genres" }, ...getGenres()];
       this.setState({ movies: getMovies(), genres });
     }
     handleDelete = (movie) => {
       const movies = this.state.movies.filter((m) => m._id !== movie._id);
       this.setState({ movies });
     };

     handleLike = (movie) => {
       const movies = [...this.state.movies];
       const index = movies.indexOf(movie);
       movies[index] = { ...movie };
       movies[index].liked = !movies[index].liked;
       this.setState({ movies });
     };

     handlePageChange = (page) => {
       this.setState({ currentPage: page });
     };

     handleGenreSelect = (genre) => {
       this.setState({ selectedGenre: genre, currentPage: 1 });
     };

     handleSort = (sortColumn) => {
       this.setState({ sortColumn });
     };
     render() {
       const { length: count } = this.state.movies;
       const {
         pageSize,
         currentPage,
         movies: allMovies,
         selectedGenre,
         sortColumn,
       } = this.state;

       if (count === 0) return <p>No movies in the DB..</p>;

       const filtered =
         selectedGenre && selectedGenre._id
           ? allMovies.filter((m) => m.genre._id === selectedGenre._id)
           : allMovies;

       const sorted = _.orderBy(filtered, [sortColumn.path], [sortColumn.order]);

       const movies = paginate(sorted, currentPage, pageSize);

       return (
         <div>
           <div className="row">
             <div className="col-3">
               <ListGorup
                 items={this.state.genres}
                 onItemSelect={this.handleGenreSelect}
                 selectedItem={this.state.selectedGenre}
               />
             </div>
             <div className="col">
               <p>Showing {filtered.length} movies in the DB. </p>
               <MoviesTable
                 movies={movies}
                 onLike={this.handleLike}
                 onDelete={this.handleDelete}
                 onSort={this.handleSort}
                 sortColumn={sortColumn}
               />

               <Pagination
                 itemsCount={filtered.length}
                 onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
                 pageSize={pageSize}
                 currentPage={currentPage}
               />
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }

   export default Movies;
   ```

The below code from file1(tableHeader.jsx) is responsible to give the column name. Not sure, why it's not coming.

```
<thead>
        <tr>
          {this.props.columns.map((column) => (
            <th
              key={column.path || column.key}
              onClick={() => this.raiseSort(column.path)}
            >
              {column.label}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
```

Looking for to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `columns` list only contains objects with the key `lable` (misspelled). It should be `label`:

```
columns = [
    { path: "title", /* not lable ! */ label: "Title" },
    { path: "genre.name", label: "Genre" },
    { path: "numberInStuck", label: "Stock" },
    { path: "dailyRentalRate", label: "Rate" },
    { key: "Like" },
    { key: "Delete" },
  ];
```

Comment: @AkhitabAcharya Happens to the best. If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted (and upvote if you like).